# How to get all coordinates from kml file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kml, google-earth

I saved a couple of coordinates from google earth as a kml file. The following code provides me with the coordinates of the first location. Any idea how to get the remaining ones?-I would somehow have to iterate over all locations.

```
from pykml import parser
 with open('list.kml', 'r') as f:
 root = parser.parse(f).getroot()
print(root.Document.Placemark.Point.coordinates)
```

Comment: can you share your .kml file example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
for i in root.findall('.//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Point'):
    print(i.coordinates)
```

Or, providing a more exact path to `Document/Placemark/Point`:

```py
for i in root.findall('{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Document/{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Placemark/{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Point'):
    print(i.coordinates)
```